# How to get two divs centered vertically and have their background fill browser

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs, but they are at the top, I want them in the middle, also each one has a background color that I'd like to fill their half of the screen.

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.español {
  background: red;
}

.english {
  background: blue;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="español">
    <a href="/es">Español</a>
  </div>
  <div class="english">
    <a href="/en">English</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about doing this?

[A picture says more than a thousand words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqfqf.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on many things, maybe divs height, position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a lot to add to your code. If you want to use flex (as you did for the container), use the following settings for the elements:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

.contenedor>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.español {
  background: red;
}

.english {
  background: blue;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="español">
    <a href="/es">Español</a>
  </div>
  <div class="english">
    <a href="/en">English</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is much better ;)

Comment: Wow, just like I wanted! (Obviously it still needs more work lol) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches you could choose.

A simple one is to set the 2 divs with abolute positionning, with each a width of 50%.

This way each div will occupy the whole height of the page and you don't have to worry about body margins or padding.

```css
.contenedor {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.espanol,
.english {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.espanol {
  background: red;
  left: 0;
}

.english {
  background: blue;
  left: 50%;
}

.contenedor a {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor">
    <div class="espanol">
      <a href="/es">Español</a>
    </div>
    <div class="english">
      <a href="/en">English</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: He want divs in the middle but full width, as he said not full height. If full height okay. But I since he said in the middle he may want to use divs height and set margin: calc(50% - half-div-height) 0; ot same with absolute top position.

Comment: I went by the drawing... I'll let the OP clarify. I think the text may need to be in the middle.

Comment: Yes! This how I wanted it! You got it right, still, as I'm learning Flexbox, I'm going with Johannes version. Thanks either way!